# Can I import custom css and font in SharePoint online or is there a custom editor web part to build content like a html editor?

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, spfx, modern-experience, spfx-webparts

Is there a custom web part that can replace the Text OOTB (see screenshot below) in sharepoint to build content pages?

I have a customer that is asking if they can lock in a font and css for their content publishers.

Is this possible with SharePoint Online?

[image]

Comment: Not possible with SharePoint out of the box functionality. You will have to develop custom SPFx web part

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to lock the font or CSS or other functionalities of SharePoint out of box Text web part.

You will have to develop the custom SPFx web part on your own for having custom funtionalities/web parts in your SharePoint sites.

You can check if there is any similar SPFx web part sample available on GitHub repository at: [SharePoint Framework Client-Side Web Part Samples & Tutorial Materials](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples)

Check this article which might help you to build SPFx web part using PnP rich text editor control: [PnP Rich Text Editor in the SharePoint Framework (SPFx) webpart](https://ravichandran.blog/2020/05/06/pnp-rich-text-editor-in-the-sharepoint-framework-spfx-webpart/)

Check the [PnP RichText control](https://pnp.github.io/sp-dev-fx-controls-react/controls/RichText/) which provides rich text editing and display capability:

[image]

**Microsoft documentations**:

1. [Overview of the SharePoint Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview)
2. [Build your first SharePoint client-side web part](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part)

Comment: thanks Ganesh. I will try the controls

Comment: Have yo used the PnP rich text editor control before?

Comment: Do you know how I can get the spkg file?

Comment: You have to download the code from Provided samples and generate the sppkg file using gulp commands.